# How to use a shape drawable together with an image?

Tags: android, android-layout, xml-drawable

I have this difficulty to have both rounded corner and a background image in my `LinearLayout`.

I know I can achive the rounded corner by using the shape drawable XML, but if I put the shape drawable as the background of my `LinearLayout` with `android:background=@drawable/rounded_corner` then I cannot assign any image to be used as a background.

How can I get both a rounded corner with a background image in my LinearLayout?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 35):

You could use [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList), which  could contain as many layers(shapes or images) as you need. You can create it either as resource or programmatically.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corners" android:id="@+id/rounded_corners"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/additional_image" android:id="@+id/additional_image" />
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer woodshy :)

I tried it but it doesn't work like what I expected. They're just being put on top of each other and the corner part from the background image is still visible behind the rounded corner shape.

Any idea how to make it to use the background image while maintaining the rounded corner shape?

Comment: so why can't you create an image with rounded corners?

Comment: That would be the easiest way, but I want to avoid that if I could.
The fact is, the image is made by someone else and if it's possible I want to do it without requesting him to change the image itself.

Comment: This worked for me as I wanted an image inside a circle, the circle is an xml shape with a 30dp for all corners and the image is just a drawable.

Comment: I find that the first layer (a shape) is scaled up when the second layer (an image) is added. The image is smaller than the shape. Is this normal? How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 3):

for those who seeks a different answer

in the xml

```
<string-array name="ulke_isimleri">
    <item>kan</item>
    <item>kebapeli</item>
</string-array>

<array name="ulke_gorselleri">
    <item>@drawable/kan1</item>
    <item>@drawable/esyalar_kebap_adana</item>
</array>
```

in the  oncreate or general

```
 String[] ulkeAdlari =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ulke_isimleri);
 TypedArray ulkeGorselleri = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.ulke_gorselleri);
```

as a function

```
 @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(int position) {

         Drawable[] drawable = new Drawable[] { 
                 ulkeGorseli.getDrawable(position   ) 
                 ,
                 new TextDrawable(ulkeAdlari[ position   ]  )
         };
        return new LayerDrawable(drawable);
    }
```