# Applying Background Image to shape

Tags: css

I'm working on a small web project and I'm currently trying to show a background image as a shaped object. Is it possible to display a regular square background image as a transformed shape like in the image below?

I tried to rotate a div, but then the image itself would be rotated as well.

What are other options that could help me archive an effect like in the image using html/css or js?

Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

Comment: can you mention your code too??

Comment: you can refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395784/applying-background-image-to-a-shape/18342177

Comment: use two layers (divs). front layers will have white colored data with css angled sided. other background will be 30% based on front layer bottom visible area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) in css to build custom shapes. Use this [website](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) from Benett Feely as a cheatsheet.

```css
article {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200) center/cover no-repeat;
  clip-path: polygon(24% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<article></article>
```

Comment: You can also use `before after` in a other way if you don't want to use *clip-path*.

Comment: that's an amazing resource. Helps a ton and didn't even knew about `clip-path` thank you Amirreza.

Comment: unfortunately still on the time lock but sure will - thanks again mate. have a good day :)